# Django logout method doesnt functionate

Tags: django

This is my first django project with login/out. On login the user is successfully redirected to his dashboard, however when I click logout nothing happens. Any ideas how can I fix this issue?

view:

```
def logout(request):
    #logout(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        auth.logout(request)
        messages.success(request, 'You are now logged out')
        return redirect('login')
```

html:

```
     {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <div id = 'dashboard' class="the-dashboard">
                <div class="prof">
                    <p ><span class = 'fntmk'>Welcome</span> {{ user.username }}</p>
                    <img src = "{% static 'images/profile-trans.jpg' %}">
                </div>
                <div class="the-panel">
                    <form action  = "{% url 'logout' %}" method = "POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                    <a class = 'fntmk'><i class="far fa-user-circle size"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Profil</a>
                    <a href="{% url 'logout' %}" class = 'logout fntmk prob' alt='exit'><span class="material-icons">logout</span><span class = 'odjavi'>Logout</span></a>
                </div></form>
            </div>
        {% else %}
            <div class="the-login">
                <form action = "{% url 'login' %}" method = "POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input type = 'text' id = 'username' class = 'username-field' placeholder = 'username' required>
                    <input type = 'password' id = 'password' placeholder = 'password' required>
                    <a href= "{% url 'login' %}"> <button class = 'btn-login'>Login</button></a>
                </form>
                <a href = "{% url 'register' %}" class = 'register fntmk'>New User?</a>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
```

urls>

```
path('register/',register, name = 'register'),
path('accounts/dashboard/',login, name = 'login'),
path('',logout, name = 'logout'),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is located in this line:

```html
<a href="{% url 'logout' %}" class = 'logout fntmk prob' alt='exit'><span class="material-icons">logout</span><span class = 'odjavi'>Logout</span></a>
```

When clicking here you're sending a GET request to your logout view.

So you can either modify your view in order to accept GET requests or a better solution is to remove this link so it actually becomes a button that submit your form.

```html
<input type="submit" value="Logout">
```

---

**Edit:**

I see you're doing the same for the login. Always use a `<input type='submit' value='...'>` or `<button type='submit'> ... </button>` to submit a form.

Comment: I totally forgot about 'submit', thank you!